# Wordpress wp_handle_upload returns empty error array

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add functionality for uploading an image through the admin settings panel, it should then be saved in the uploads directory. I wrote this code to achieve that, but instead of returning the file, it returns an odd error array. Anybody know why?

```
if(!empty($_FILES[Constants::$option_name]))
            {
                $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
                $urls = wp_handle_upload($_FILES[Constants::$option_name], $upload_overrides);
                $temp = $urls["url"];
                return $temp;   
            }
```

This is the die and dump from the $_FILES[Constants::$option_name];

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { ["logo"]=> string(11) "Logo-01.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(1) { ["logo"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { ["logo"]=> string(26) "C:\xampp74\tmp\phpB661.tmp" } ["error"]=> array(1) { ["logo"]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { ["logo"]=> int(315767) } }
```

And finally this is what `wp_handle_upload()` returns.

```
array(1) { ["error"]=> array(1) { ["logo"]=> int(0) } }
```